# Merge rows in R with all but one duplicate value

Tags: r, merge, duplicates, tidyverse

I searched for an answer to this but couldn't find what I am sure is an incredibly easy fix.

I have a dataset like so

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 2),
                  year1 = c(0,  1, 1),
                  year2 = c(1,  0, 0))
```

As you can see the ID 1 is pseudo-duplicated as it has created a new row for each year, I am trying to merge the two rows together so that each ID is one row  like so

```
output <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2),
                     year1 = c(1, 1),
                     year2 = c(1, 0))
```

Any suggestions on how to do this ? I'm sure its very easy.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(ID) %>% 
  dplyr::summarize(across(starts_with("year"), ~ cumsum(.))) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(row_number() == n())

     ID year1 year2
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     1
2     2     1     0
```

This works by summing down the columns (`cumsum`) within `ID`. `filter` takes the last row within your group-by variable.